# Can only have a link to lifelines in Sequence Diagram if there is a link in UML classes?

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

Is there a must that in the UML class diagram, if two classes are not linked, then there cannot have a connection between those classes's lifeline? For example if I have a void function `public void sample(actor a)` since it's just a parameter so there is no link between two classes, but is it possible that in sequence diagram that that is a link between two to perform certain actions?

I think it can be and I actually found some images to prove it(not too sure if I have misunderstood the images) but my tutor says I'm wrong that there is no link between two lifelines if there is no link between two classes. So I'm not too sure about the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "link" you actually mean "message" (solid arrow), you need an association. A message is equal to an invocation of a class' operation. To be able to do that, the caller must have a reference to the called class - an association.

Answer (score 0):

No , is is not necessary to have association or any other relationship defined explicitly between classes which instances communicate in class diagrams. If you need to depict that instances of specific classes are connected in interaction (communicates) , you can use Collaboration element and connectors. Connector defines communication relationship, but does not define how it is physically implemented. In some cases it can by realized by link of course.
Message between lifelines implicitly defines communication relationship between lifeline's types.